# Python / print and assign random number every time

Tags: python-2.7, random, string-formatting

I'm trying to generate a random integral and assign it to the variable.

```
import random
import time

Op = lambda: random.randint(1300, 19000)
op = "https://duckduckgo.com/html?q="

variable = int(Op())

grow = 0
while x < 3:
    print(Op())
    grow = grow + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

In here everything works fine, function "print" prints different result every time with 3 attempts.
However when I want to format this code like this:

```
Op = lambda: random.randint(1300, 19000)
op = "https://duckduckgo.com/html?q="

Op1 = int(Op())
pop = str("{}{}").format(op, Op1)


grow = 0
while grow < 3:
    print(pop)
    grow = grow + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then the function print gives me the same number three times.

For example:

```
>>>https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=44543
>>>https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=44543
>>>https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=44543
```

And I would like to get three random numbers. For example:

```
    >>>https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=44325
    >>>https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=57323
    >>>https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=35691
```

I was trying to use %s - %d formatting but the result is the same.

Comment: You're printing the same string 3 times... why _shouldn't_ it look the same?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions are by definition anonymous. If you need to "remember" a lambda's procedure, just use `def` statement. But actually you don't even need this:

```
import random
import time


url_base = "https://duckduckgo.com/html?q={}"

grow = 0
while grow < 3:
    print(url_base.format(random.randint(1300, 19000))
    grow = grow + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Your main problem is that you are trying to assign fixed values to variables and expect them to behave like procedures.
You need to apply randomness at every iteration. Instead you calculate a random number once and plug it in to every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never changes the value of 'pop'.

In you first example you are creating instance of Op in every iteration but in second example you created instance once outside the loop and print the same value.

Try this:

```
    Op = lambda: random.randint(1300, 19000)
    op = "https://duckduckgo.com/html?q="
    grow = 0
    while grow < 3:
      pop = str("{}{}").format(op, int(Op()))
      print(pop)
      grow = grow + 1
      time.sleep(1)
```